# SQL посчитать кол-во в CASE

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

у меня есть таблица в SQL Lite в которых колонки City, Gender, Age in Yrs. и вот такая задача:

- подсчитать рабочих по полу в каждой возрастной группе(0-20, 20-40, 40-60, 60-80, 90-100) для каждого города

Я запутался с этими запросами в CASE, кто сможет подсказать почему не считает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текст текстом приведите пожалуйста

Comment: у вас `count` должен быть в том же запросе где и `group by`